# kivy get children of id

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

python 3.4.3 kivy 1.9.0

I am trying to retrieve the list of children Images only via ID.
this is to remove or clear_widgets all the Images from that list

kv is set up similarly to this:

```
<Gui>:
    grid: grid_1
    BoxLayout:
        Orientation: 'horizontal'
        Button:
            on_press: app.do_something()
        GridLayout:
            id: grid_1
            cols: 4
```

the py file is like so:

```
class GuiApp(App):
    list = ['test','test2',...]

    def build(self):
        G = Gui()
        for i in list:
            G.grid.add_widget(Image(source=i))

    def do_something(self):
        G = Gui()
        G.grid.clear_widgets([i for i in G.grid.children if type(i) is Image])

class Gui(BoxLayout):
    grid = ObjectProperty(None)
```

What is supposed to happen is the grid layout is supposed to clear all the Images that were earlier added to the widget via the for-loop, when I run this, nothing disapears, all the images remain, and I get an error in the CMD window saying`[WARNING] <kivy.uix.gridlayout.GridLayout object at 0x00000000080B90A8> have no cols or rows set, layout is not triggered.`

Answer (score 0):

The first problem with your code is that your `build` method creates a `Gui` object but never returns it. You should add `return G` at the end of the method.

Then, on your `do_something` method you're currently creating a new `Gui` object by doing `G = Gui()` again. To access the same `G` object you created on the `build` method you should've created it as a `self.G`.

Here's what it should look like:

```
class GuiApp(App):
    list = ['test','test2',...]

    def build(self):
        self.G = Gui()
        for i in list:
            self.G.grid.add_widget(Image(source=i))
        return self.G

    def do_something(self):
        self.G.grid.clear_widgets([i for i in self.G.grid.children if type(i) is Image])

class Gui(BoxLayout):
    grid = ObjectProperty(None)
```